# How to change the font color (Foreground) in a NavigationViewItem?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

you will see I am creating a UWP app and I am using the (NavigationView) as the main menu, in NavigationViewItem I have managed to change the background, the selection line, etc. but I could not change the font color

Screenshot of sample

[https://i.imgur.com/Oc9ffxG.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsfZi.png)

my xaml code:

```
 <NavigationView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="nvSample" PaneDisplayMode="Top" SelectionChanged="NvSample_SelectionChanged"
              IsSettingsVisible="True" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed">


        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item1" Tag="Home_Page" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="38" Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Instalpage" Tag="Install_Page" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item3" Tag="SamplePage3" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item4" Tag="SamplePage4" />


        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame" >

        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                    <NavigationThemeTransition>
                        <DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo />
                    </NavigationThemeTransition>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
         </Frame>

            <NavigationView.PaneFooter>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!--<NavigationViewItem Icon="SelectAll" Content="Select all" Foreground="White" />
                    <NavigationViewItem Icon="Help" Content="Help" />-->

                </StackPanel>

            </NavigationView.PaneFooter>

    </NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I could not change the font color

You could use a `TextBlock` control as the NavigationViewItem's content and then you could set the `Foreground` property for TextBlock control.

Please see the following code sample for reference:

```
<NavigationView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="nvSample" PaneDisplayMode="Top"
          IsSettingsVisible="True" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Tag="Home_Page" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="38" Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <NavigationViewItem.Content>
                    <TextBlock Text="Menu Item1" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
                </NavigationViewItem.Content>
            </NavigationViewItem>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Instalpage" Tag="Install_Page" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item3" Tag="SamplePage3" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item4" Tag="SamplePage4" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame" >

            <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <NavigationThemeTransition>
                        <DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo />
                    </NavigationThemeTransition>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Frame.ContentTransitions>
        </Frame>
        <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--<NavigationViewItem Icon="SelectAll" Content="Select all" Foreground="White" />
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Help" Content="Help" />-->
            </StackPanel>
        </NavigationView.PaneFooter>
    </NavigationView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

NavigationViewItem does have a property called Foreground and it worked for me

```
<NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item1" Foreground="Black" Tag="Home_Page" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Instalpage" Foreground="Black" Tag="Install_Page" />
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item3" Foreground="Black" Tag="SamplePage3" />
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item4" Foreground="Black" Tag="SamplePage4" />
</NavigationView.MenuItems>
```